# Using conditional statement in bind-attr Handlebars Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

How can I use a conditional statement inside my Handlebars template with limited results.  I can get it to work fine if there is only one button that is clicking because it is static then but when I test against two buttons no dice -

```
<a {{bind-attr class="isClicked:clicked"}} {{action 'raiseValue'}}><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>
<a {{bind-attr class="isClicked:clicked"}} {{action 'lowerValue'}}><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
```

And in my controller -

```
selected: '', 
isClicked: function (sender) {
    return this.get('selected') === sender;
}.property('selected'),
actions: {
    raiseValue: function() { this.set('selected', 'raise'); }
}
```

**What I would expect to happen** -

When the value of `clicked` changes it would pass that in to my anon function and return whether the value of clicked === the clicked value of the object passed in.

**What does happen**

sender === 'isClicked' in that scenario

I have tried using a conditional statement in the binding but that isn't working at all -

```
<a {{bind-attr class="(isClicked === 'raise'):clicked"}} {{action 'raiseValue'}}><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>
```

Basically I am trying to mimic how a radio button works I guess...  Any thoughts as to what is going wrong here?

Comment: You're not setting the `isClicked` property to the function. You're setting it to the result of calling `.property('clicked')` at setup time.

Comment: Hmm where at?  In the template I want it to evaluate and if true apply a class named clicked - I think I confused the question by naming the property in my controller 'clicked' also which is what I want to compare it against.  Let me update question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass in parameters into a computed property like that. The simples solution is to split it like this:

```
isRaiseClicked: function () {
    return this.get('selected') === "raise";
}.property('selected'),

isLowerClicked: function () {
    return this.get('selected') === "lower";
}.property('selected'),

<a {{bind-attr class="isRaiseClicked:clicked"}} {{action 'raiseValue'}}><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>
<a {{bind-attr class="isLowerClicked:clicked"}} {{action 'lowerValue'}}><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
```

Comment: Just doesn't seem like a solution that would scale well - is performing logical tests in the template a no-no?  Seems like a pretty basic need...

Comment: I accepted and +1'd but would welcome an elaboration on why and why using logical tests in the template is a no-no if you get a chance.

Comment: There's just no way of passing in parameters into properties like that. I guess the philosophy here is that templates should be only templates and all the logic should go into the view or controller. However, if you wanted to, you could just split the above out into a component that encapsulates that logic.